# Firefox 15 shows HTML5 pages zoomed out 33%, no setting to override this

Tags: html, firefox, web-applications, zooming

I've used Firefox for webdesign work because I'm used to and like Firebug and Web Developer Toolbar. I'm now making a page template and am having trouble getting a sense of how everything looks, since it's zoomed out. Non-HTML5 web pages have the correct zoom level.

I've googled a lot, but not found anything pertinent.

I would like to turn off this behavior, with some -moz-* directive if necessary, since it shows the web pages differently than all the other HTML5 browsers.

How?

If the problem is new since 15.0.1 for Mac, I'll accept downgrading temporarily if you can link a version that fixes it.

NOTE: This has nothing to do with the page-zoom that users can change with Ctrl + and -.

**EDIT:
Hm, support.mozilla.com is normal scale (it seems). Can someone help me find what HTML5 code turn off (supposedly) the HiDPI Canvas or whatever it is causing this?**

Comment: For example google.com and stackoverflow.com also show zoomed out, since they're HTML5, and vworker.com shows normal, since it's not HTML5. It has nothing to do with my web page. All these sites show normal in all other browsers, as does mine.

Comment: That's quite odd.  I'm not seeing any such "zoom out" effect, nor were there any code changes to trigger it.  Are any of your "font.size.inflation.*" preferences set to non-default values?  Does the problem appear in safe mode?  With a clean profile?

Comment: Have you tried <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> ? Just a thought

Comment: But I want to also see other pages (pages not coded by me) at the correct zoom level. My OSX version is 10.6.8.

Comment: hm, support.mozilla.com is normal scale (it seems). Can someone help me find what HTML5 code turn off (supposedly) the HiDPI Canvas or whatever it is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add-on [Default Full Zoom Level](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/default-fullzoom-level/) fixes it.

Firefox 15 stores individual zoom levels on a domain level. Now, the page I was testing was on my own domain, I had never visited it before (except in an old version of Firefox which I uninstalled - where it had correct zoom), and I had never zoomed it out (on top of which Ctrl+0 doing nothing, which tells me the browser has decided what 100% means). This should mean the zoom level is assigned to domains automatically according to a hidden rule (hopefully) which cannot be changed.

But with the plugin you can. Just installing it fixed my page.

For other sites, like this one, it seems you will have to make some settings. The association between incorrect zoom and HTML5 pages is not confirmed, even if I haven't found a non-HTML5 page that doesn't zoom correctly.

Comment: zoom zoom zoom zoom zoom zoom zoom zoom <-- a few extra for good measure. wth, it's a cool word. :)